# Is it possible to take arbitrary number of elements from array in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My dataframe has two array columns. I want to take elements from first column whose indices are in the second column. For example, I have the following dataset

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
   [
      {
         'text': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
         'indices': [0, 2, 4],
      },
   ]
)
```

So I want to have columns with value `['0', '2', '4].

Is it possible to achieve this without writingUDF?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `expr` function with `TRANSFORM` and `element_at` to select elements from the first array based on the indices provided in the second array.

E.g.:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn(
    "selected_text",
    expr("TRANSFORM(indices, i -> element_at(text, i))")
)
df.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, or if someone wants to use zero-based indices, `getItem` can be used instead of `element_at`.

```
result = df.withColumn(
        'selected',
        F.transform(
            F.col('indices'),
            lambda ind: F.col('text').getItem(ind),
        ),
    )
```